# Mapfish Print on linux server doesn't print any texts to png or jpg outup formats

Tags: printing, mapfish

I'm using Mapfish Print 1.2 on Windows and everyhing works correctly. But on Linux server, Mapfish Print doesn't print any texts to output formats like png or jpg. It does work only with pdf.

Do you have any ideas, what's the problem?